# List docker images in a repository using c# .net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-image

I am trying to get a particular docker image with tag from a particular repository, but when i try to run the code it says "Not Found" exception.

Please let me know the SDK for the same used in .net 6.0.

I tried the below code:

```c
DockerClient client1 = new DockerClientConfiguration(
new Uri("https://docker.env.repositoryname.com/")
).CreateClient();

var img = client1.Images.InspectImageAsync("imageName", default).Result;
```

Comment: Did you filter the images using params?


var images = await client.Images.ListImagesAsync(new ImagesListParameters
{
    All = true,
    MatchName = "repository_name"
});

Comment: MatchName is not a property for ImagesListParameters.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static async Task<IList<ImagesListResponse>> CheckImageExists(string name, string tag){
    IDockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration().CreateClient();
    ImagesListParameters parameters = new() {
        Filters = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, bool>>()
    };
    var tagStr = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag) ? "*" : tag;
    parameters.Filters.Add("reference", new Dictionary<string, bool> {
        {$"{name}:{tagStr}", true}
    });
    return await client.Images.ListImagesAsync(parameters);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).